# Android Insert mutliple phone numbers in an editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, contacts, phone-number

I managed to create a button that launches the contact book and returns a phone number to an editText, upon selection. How do I insert multiple phone numbers into the editText (a.k.a sending sms to a group of people instead of one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to separate the numbers with comma(",") , so that get list of numbers as

```
String number =  et.getText().toString();

String[] numArr = number.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding multiple phone numbers inside the edit text seperating with SPACE  then when you get the text from edit text. do things below...

```
String temp = edittext.getText().toString();

String[] tempArr = temp.split(" ");
```

tempArr will contain all the numbers inputed in edit text....

Comment: Thank so much for the answer . Really of great help.